# To make the GCD code nicer and less verbose

Tags: haskell

I am using Euclid's algorithm for computing  GCD(M,N), the greatest common divisor of two integers M and N.

Though this code works well, I felt it's bit cumbersome to wrap it with max, min, and abs for both variables (a, b).

1. Can anyone suggest a better way to make the code less verbose?
2. I found the built-in gcd type was defined as gcd :: Integer a => a -> a -> a, but I cannot simply use it. What do I need to change in order to reuse the type definition?

```
gcd2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd2 a b =
    let x = max (abs a) (abs b)
        y = min (abs a) (abs b)
        in if (y == 0) || (x == y && x > 0) 
           then x 
           else gcd2 y (x-y)
```

Well, inspired by [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi), I changed the code as below.

```
gcd3 :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd3 a b | a <  0 = gcd3 (-a) b
         | b <  0 = gcd3 a (-b)
         | b >  a = gcd3 b a
         | b == a || b == 0 = a
         | otherwise = gcd3 b (a-b)
```

This is the best I can do. :)

Comment: You can reuse the built-in `gcd`: this is more generic, since it allows to work with any `Integral` type, so `Int`, `Integer`, `Int16`, `Word8`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's kind of exercise|practice for me to learn Haskell. I am trying to invent some wheels as I can easily compared with existing ones.

Comment: I would avoid `min` and `max` and simply use `gcd x y = if x>y then gcd y x else ...` where in the `...` you can assume that `x <= y` and act accordingly. You could split the definition into multiple equations using guards. Also, the `abs` part should only be used once, not at every recursive step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [how it is implemented in base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#gcd):

```hs
gcd             :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
gcd x y         =  gcd' (abs x) (abs y)
                   where gcd' a 0  =  a
                         gcd' a b  =  gcd' b (a `rem` b)
```

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by chi in his answer, to avoid using abs in each recursive step I’d define a GCD local function where you pass the absolute value of the arguments. This way the implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
gcd :: Int -> Int -> Int
gcd a b = gcd' (abs a) (abs b)
  where gcd' a 0 = a
        gcd' a b = gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

Comment: That is good.  It avoids both the unnecessary checks for sign on every iteration (we only need to do it once) and it takes advantage of the fact that we know which of the two arguments is larger after every iteration to avoid the comparison.

The only potential issue is that it doesn't insure that the first argument is the larger one on the initial iteration.

Comment: Yes, we could check that; however, if `a < b` the algorithm would simply take one step more: `if a < b then a % b = a` so the first recursive call would be
`gcd' a b = gcd' b (mod a b) = gcd' b a` (resulting in the swapped arguments with the larger first).
So this way the algorithm is still correct but in my opinion more legible than the version that explicitly checks if `a` is greater than `b` before calling `gcd'`